# what is equivalent to Java packages in iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, package

I want to know which is the equivalent concept of Java packages in iPhone. Is it bundling or Static library?

Answer (score 4):

**Java Packages** imply **namespace**, which **doesn't exist in Objective-C**. However, XCode supports **Groups** for managing common code (basically placed in their own directory). **Libraries** are typically delivered as a **Framework**.

This are added to a project as a **framework**.

For example,

1. Address Book
2. OpenGL
3. Third Party

Answer (score 2):

Java packages are used to avoids namespace collision, which is a situation where two pieces of code have the same name but do different things.

To do this in objective C - add prefix your class names with initials. All class created in cocoa framework have a prefix 'NS'. You can define your own prefix for your code.